# Proving a function is differential

Tags: analysis, limits

This question asks me to prove that $f(x)$$=$$x^4$$(2+sin(1/x))$ is differential for x$\neq$0.

I attempted to solve this using the limit definition but on similar problems, the solutions offered evaluate the limit with $(0+h)$ instead of $(x+h)$. Why is this? Can I use that same approach here and evaluate with $x=0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$x\mapsto \frac {1}{x} $ is diffetentiable for $x\ne0$

$x\mapsto \sin (x) $ is differentiable at $\Bbb R $

thus $f $ is differentiable for $x\ne 0$ and

$$f'(x)=8x^3+\sin (\frac {1}{x})(4x^3-x^2) $$

On the other hand,

for $x\ne0 \;\; |f (x)|\le 3|x^4|$ thus we can put $f (0)=0$

$$\lim_0\frac {f (x)-0}{x-0}=0=f'(0) $$